# How to remove _id from aggregate $match & $group query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to display unique records grouped by the particular slug passed in.

My output in postman looks like this though:

```
"subcats": [
  {
    "_id": {
      "subcategory": {
        "_id": "5d2b42c47b454712f4db7c37",
        "name": "shirts"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

when my desired output is:

```
"subcats": [
  {
        "_id": "5d2b42c47b454712f4db7c37",
        "name": "shirts"
  }
]
```

An example of a product in the database:

```
    "_id": "5d39eff7a48e6e30ace831dc",
    "name": "A colourful shirt",
    "description": "A nice colourful t-shirt",
    "category": {
        "_id": "5d35faa67b19e32ab3dc91ec",
        "name": "clothing",
        "catSlug": "clothing"
    },
    "subcategory": {
        "_id": "5d2b42c47b454712f4db7c37",
        "name": "shirts",
        "catSlug": "shirts"
    },
    "price": 19
}
```

I don't want that top level `_id` there with everything nested inside of it.

I tried using `$project` but then I just end up with an empty array.

```
  const products = await Product.find({ "category.catSlug": catslug }).select({
    name: 1,
    description: 1,
    price: 1,
    category: 1
  });

const subcats = await Product.aggregate([
  { $match: { "category.catSlug": catslug } },
  { $group: { _id: { subcategory: "$subcategory" } } }
  { $project: { _id: 0, name: 1 } }
]);

Promise.all([products, subcats]);
  res.status(200).json({
    products,
    subcats
  });
```

Comment: Would be nice if you can provide sample data.

Comment: @HardikShah, what data would you like to see in particular and I can post it here

Comment: Below answer is looks good. But the actual data of `products` will help to write meaningful/optimized query if possible. Can you paste here sample data of product? One record is enough.

Comment: @HardikShah, I have updated my question, I hope that is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have understood from your question is you need product by category and all sub categories as a list.

Below is the aggregation:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
 { $match: { "category.catSlug": "clothing" } },
 { $group: { _id: '$subcategory.name', subCategory: { $first : "$subcategory" }}},
 { $group: { _id: null, subcats: { $push:  {_id: "$subCategory._id", name: "$subCategory.name" }}}},
 { $project: {_id: 0, subcats: 1}}
]);
```

> Note: You can directly push "$subcategory" but it will have `catSlug` inside object

**Output:**

```
{
  "_id" : null,
  "subcats" : [{
    "_id" : "5d2b42c47b454712f4db7c37",
    "name" : "shirts"
  }, 
  {
    "_id" : "5d2b42c47b454712f4db7c37",
    "name" : "pents"
  }]
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for this. It isn't exactly what I am looking for though. I want to ultimately create a filter where the user can click on a subcategory. I need the records to come back as individual records. I have updated my question to show the desired format

Comment: Thank you, this is better but just 2 issues. It is showing duplicate records, where with my query I was getting unique records ie: no duplicates and now I have an array inside an array which isn't what I want.

Comment: @user10980228, Issue 1) What is the unique thing from which we can remove duplicate records? I mean using category name or it's id? 2) Array inside an Array means? You will have only one array which is for `subcats `.

Comment: 1. Subcategory name. So, it should only show, SHIRTS, SHORTS and not SHIRTS, SHIRTS, SHORTS. 2. I am getting back `subcats: [{ "_id": null, "subcats": [{"_id:": "......"`

Comment: @user10980228, Updated answer please check. And I am really don't understand why you are getting Array inside Array while I am getting it perfect. It is something that is missed here to define?

Comment: Array inside array must be something due to `Promise.all` I think.

Comment: This is looking much better. Only issue now is array inside of an array which is not what I want. You could be right regarding Promise.all however my other query is not resulting in an array inside of an array. Does $project not create another array?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to assign the required data in other fields while projection then define the _id to 0 as given below

```
      {$project:{subcat_data:'$_id.subcategory'},_id:0}
```

Comment: Thanks. I added your code but get an error: Error Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators